# I can't display a map with fragment

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, fragment

I have aproblem displaying the map on my galaxy S4 4.2.2,in fact,I'am a new android student,and I tried to work with the fragment in map,this is a part of my class Map:

```
public class Map extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap Gmap;
    private static LatLng Myposition, position;
    Marker marker, myplace;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

    private Double latitude;
    private Double longitude;
    private Double t1, t2;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentmap, null, false);
        //Gmap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        Gmap = ((MapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        Gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        GPSTracker gps = new GPSTracker(getActivity());
        // check if GPS enabled
        if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            System.out.println("latitude" + latitude);
            System.out.println("longitude" + longitude);
        .... }
```

those are the errors:
[image]

thanks for any Help

Comment: You just wanna display a map with fragment in an app?

Comment: You are using a deprecated API, getMap() is now replaced by getMapAsync()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display a map with fragment, there is a good open source sample [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/hellomap-android).

You can clone it and try. I have tried and it works.

Don't forget put you API key in your `AndroidManifest.xml` such that

```
<meta-data
          android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
          android:value="YOUR_API_KEY"/>
```

To know how to get the Key from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#the_google_maps_api_key).

Also you can refer to [this](http://javapapers.com/android/show-map-in-android/), it may helps.